# XML parsing to a MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, xml, parsing, jdbc

I have been working on this piece of code to parse my XML file into a MySQL database. Every tutorial I have seen online parses individually like this code I've been working on. From here I would like to loop it in a way which instead of adding each field individually, if iterate it through the XML file and define how many fields need to be created inside of the table. Does anyone have any such tutorials they are aware of or possibly a short example how I could get started for this? Example I would not like to re-edit my program each time i decide to add another characteristic for a customer.

```
package xSQLTEST;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;

public class InsertXMLData {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/brandonDB",
                                                         "root",
                                                         "Absolute!");
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new File("C:\\testXML.xml"));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            System.out.println("Root element of the doc is "
                               + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
            NodeList listOfPersons = doc.getElementsByTagName("row");
            for (int s = 0; s < listOfPersons.getLength(); s++) {
                Node firstPersonNode = listOfPersons.item(s);
                if (firstPersonNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element firstPersonElement = (Element) firstPersonNode;
                    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                    NodeList CustIdList = firstPersonElement.getElementsByTagName("CustId");
                    Element CustIdElement = (Element) CustIdList.item(0);

                    NodeList textIDList = CustIdElement.getChildNodes();
                    String CustId = ((Node) textIDList.item(0)).getNodeValue()
                                                               .trim();

                    NodeList NameList = firstPersonElement.getElementsByTagName("Name");
                    Element NameElement = (Element) NameList.item(0);

                    NodeList textNMList = NameElement.getChildNodes();
                    String Name = ((Node) textNMList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim();

                    NodeList CityList = firstPersonElement.getElementsByTagName("City");
                    Element CityElement = (Element) CityList.item(0);

                    NodeList textCTList = CityElement.getChildNodes();
                    String City = ((Node) textCTList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim();

                    int i = st.executeUpdate("insert into customer(CustId,Name,City) values('"
                                             + CustId
                                             + "','"
                                             + Name
                                             + "','"
                                             + City
                                             + "')");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Data is successfully inserted!");

        }
        catch (Exception err) {
            System.out.println(" " + err.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

XML FILE that I am using but would like to possibly add more details about the customer in the future.

```
<Customers>
   <row> 
      <CustId>1</CustId>
      <Name>Woodworks</Name>
      <City>Baltimore</City>
   </row>
   <row> 
      <CustId>2</CustId>
      <Name>Software Solutions</Name>
      <City>Boston</City>
   </row>
   <row> 
      <CustId>3</CustId>
      <Name>Food Fantasies</Name>
      <City>New York</City>
   </row>
</Customers>
```

BUFFER READER INSERTED AND WORKING:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("c:\\testXML.xml")));
String line;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

while((line=br.readLine())!= null){
    sb.append(line.trim());
}
String strFileContent = sb.toString();
```

Comment: Would you mind if the answer used Jsoup (another xml parser) instead?

Comment: Try using $xml = simplexml_load_file($url). Here is the documentation for simplexml: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml.asp. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Jsoup, you can do this:

```java
private static void parseXml(String xml) {
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(xml);
    StringBuilder queryBuilder;
    StringBuilder columnNames;
    StringBuilder values;
    
    for (Element row : doc.select("row")) {   
        // Start the query   
        queryBuilder = new StringBuilder("insert into customer(");
        columnNames = new StringBuilder();
        values = new StringBuilder();
        
        for (int x = 0; x < row.children().size(); x++) {
            
            // Append the column name and it's value 
            columnNames.append(row.children().get(x).tagName());
            values.append(row.children().get(x).text());
            
            if (x != row.children().size() - 1) {
                // If this is not the last item, append a comma
                columnNames.append(",");
                values.append(",");
            }
            else {
                // Otherwise, add the closing paranthesis
                columnNames.append(")");
                values.append(")");
            }                                
        }
   
        // Add the column names and values to the query
        queryBuilder.append(columnNames);
        queryBuilder.append(" values(");
        queryBuilder.append(values);

        // Print the query
        System.out.println(queryBuilder);
    }
}
```

Output:

```sql
insert into customer(custid,name,city) values(1,Woodworks,Baltimore)
insert into customer(custid,name,city) values(2,Software Solutions,Boston)
insert into customer(custid,name,city) values(3,Food Fantasies,New York)
```

This allows us to add as many new columns or rows as we wish. For example, I added a few bits to your original XML, and without modification to the java code, the output was:

```sql
insert into customer(custid,name,city,age) values(1,Woodworks,Baltimore,21)
insert into customer(custid,name,city,age) values(2,Software Solutions,Boston,21)
insert into customer(custid,name,city,age) values(3,Food Fantasies,New York,21)
insert into customer(custid,name,city,age) values(4,Crazy Hat Store,London,21)
```

**EDIT :**

To import the XML from file, the method would look like this:

```java
private static String loadXml(String filePath) {
    try {
        StringBuilder xml = new StringBuilder();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(filePath)); // i.e. C:\\testXML.xml
        
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            xml.append(scanner.nextLine());
        }
        return xml.toString();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

And then my main method looked like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    parseXml(loadXml(filePath));
}
```

Comment: How would I apply this to the executeUpdate? Wouldn't I have to still edit that throughout my program each and everytime i decide to add another entity?

Comment: I've updated the code for you. I've just tested it, and it allows you to add as many columns or rows as you wish without having to modify the code.

Comment: I understand this is a completely noobie question, but I am getting a "The method select(String) is undefined for the type Document". I'm trying to pass parse the xml file in and its not completely working. and as for "executeUpdate("insert into customer(CustId,Name,City) values('"+CustId+"','"+Name+"','"+City+"')");" it would become executeUpdate(queryBuilder) correct? Also I'll be sure to rate your question after I figure out this small issue. Thanks a ton!

Comment: I've tried importing the jar etc from the select and its still not working. The children method is doing the same.

Comment: It's probably because you're importing the wrong `Document` class -- it should be `import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;`. Just remove the old imports, and use this instead. Also, if you have any more problems adding the Jsoup jar, just let me know

Comment: I've added the soap jar, and have that all working. My question for you though is how did you import the string xml file? Ive tried buffer reader etc? would you be willing to update your code one last time on how you brought in my XML file? Thanks!

Comment: Just using the `Scanner` class. I've edited to include the method I used. *Bear in mind the only reason these 2 methods are static is because I was calling them from `public static void main(String[] args)`, and I was too lazy to create an object of my class :)*